# GDB Hangs after "New Thread" on macOS

Tags: terminal

I have built GDB from source on macOS 12.0 and codesigned it. However, every time I try to debug a program, I get this:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10000324f: file main.cpp, line 50.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/fluzzlesnuff/Documents/C++/a.out
[New Thread 0x2a03 of process 2389]
```

and then GDB hangs. I have been compiling C++ programs with g++. Here are some things I have tried:

1. Compile with -g option.
2. Compile with -ggdb option.
3. Compile with -ggdb3 option.
4. Run with `sudo`
5. Kill and re-run gdb repeatedly.
6. Try different binaries.
7. Disable SIP
8. Add more breakpoints.
9. `set startup-with-shell off` in `.gdbinit`

I do *not* get taskgated / Mach Port errors; only the New Thread message.

I realize that this is a near-duplicate of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377934/mysterious-gdb-hangs-after-clean-build), but I didn't see a working answer on that question.

For reference, here are my versions:

```
$ g++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.2
```

Comment: As you are  using clang it might be a better idea to use lldb (as used in Xcode) as the debugger. I think gdb is more aligned to use with GNU cc which your g++ is not

Comment: `g++` is an alias of `gcc` with some C++ options, so it’s definitely GNU. https://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: That is not what you show in the question the result of g++ --version says it isclang

Comment: I was kind of wondering about that. I just learned that g++ is really clang++ in disguise. This is likely the source of my problems.

Comment: If you're amenable to using `lldb` you can sidestep this altogether and have a working debugger. I wasn't able to get `gdb` working and hit this same error. No such issue with lldb which provides very similar functionality.

Comment: @MattKneiser does `lldb` have a `gdb` `follow-fork-mode child` equivalent that allows it to take the place of `gdb` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, attention to detail was the issue. I saw that `g++ --version` reported `clang`, but I didn’t think about it enough. I had assumed that GDB was the problem, not my compiler. I’m not sure why Apple linked g++ to clang++, since that’s quite misleading. This little oversight made me spend 8 months writing C++ on my phone (vi on a 60-character wide display is not my ideal IDE).

What I did to get *real* g++:

1. Install gcc with Homebrew
2. Soft-link (`ln -s`) gcc-11 and g++-11 from `/usr/local/Cellar/` to `/usr/local/bin/`
3. `unhash` (at least in zsh) gcc and g++, or else `gcc` will continue to expand to `/usr/bin/clang`

GDB is working great now.

Comment: Why do you need gnu c++? Clang does most things as well and for macos and ios it is probably better.  With clang you can use xcode which is a lot better ide than vi on an iPhone. Also doing most work in c you do not call gcc or clang on the command line but a build system eg make and for hat you want to se CC to the full path and don't rely on your $PATH

Comment: I’m not able to debug programs compiled with clang using gdb. I tried using Xcode, but it was much more than I needed for writing small utilities. I’m writing command-line utilities, so I find it easiest to `g++ *.cpp`, then run `a.out` with whatever arguments I desire.

Comment: Then use lldb to debug

Comment: I am running into same issue despite following above steps. I am using GDB version 2.1 and using MacOS Monterey 12.6.1

Comment: @TusharJadhav GDB 2.1 is very old; is there any reason you need to use such an old version?

Comment: @tjcaul Sorry, that was a typo. I am using GDB version 12.1 and not 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
It seems that I was wrong, it still only works sporadically, sometimes it hangs sometimes it doesn't. It just happened to work three times in a row after running this command :(

I had the same problem and fought for hours trying to install gdb on mac. Found this [blog](https://timnash.co.uk/getting-gdb-to-semi-reliably-work-on-mojave-macos/) that said that I should not have run

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

which I never did. So I tried it and it worked. Another possible solution was to run gdb with sudo every time but I felt this was better. No idea why they worked but they did, I hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: I didn’t run this, but after a recent update to the Command Line Developer Tools, I was asked for Touch-ID confirmation when I started up `gdb`. That makes me think your command, or some form of it, was run during the update, and now does a security check when running developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

This hang hits gdb bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24069

You can install gdb from this source with patch:

```
brew install --force --build-from-source domq/gdb/gdb  # a patched version based on 10.1
```

or you can

```
brew update
brew install gdb # use gdb 12.1
```

It works for me, and I found it from this link: https://gist.github.com/mike-myers-tob/9a6013124bad7ff074d3297db2c98247